# Access Table - Expression Builder unexpected results

Tags: if-statement, ms-access, logic, expression

I have a huge CSV data file that generates 500,000+ rows and 70+ columns, running Excel queries over this much data causes my desktop to crash.
As an alternative i've managed to import the CSV into Access.
The majority of the data fields i need to review/consider within further calculations i've imported as "double" field type.
I guess the first question is should i use single rather than double?  The values i am considering will only ever report to 2 decimal places.

Within the imported table i've created some new columns, as i need to validate that the sum of underlying values equals the totals reported.

A sum of 5 underlying columns (called SUMofService)
[Ancillary Costs] + [Incidental Costs] + [One-Off Costs] + [Ongoing Costs] + [Transaction Costs]

I've not reviewed all 500,000 rows, but this formula seems to be summing the values correctly.

Using this value i've then created a new column to compare this total to the total in the report

IIF([SUMofService] = [Total Service],"Match","No Match")

This also seems to work as expected, but there are instances where this field returns a false.
Looking at the underlying numbers in [SUMofService] and [TotalService] they match, so i am confused as to why i am seeing the false results.

Could anyone review what i've detailed, and perhaps provide a steer as to whether i've considered something incorrectly.

There are probably better ways to achieve what i'm trying to do, but i haven't really used Access since school and you forget quite a bit in 30 years!!

Any responses are much appreciated - i've googled this as much as i can, but not 100% what to ask, and some responses are so far beyond my level of thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> should I use single rather than double?
> The values I am considering will only ever report to 2 decimal places.

Neither. Use *Currency*.

That will also provide correct results for:

```
IIF([SUMofService] = [Total Service],"Match","No Match")
```

Using Double or, indeed, Single will cause floating point errors - as in this classic example:

```
? 10.1 - 10.0
 9.99999999999996E-02 

' thus:

? 10.1 - 10.0 = 0.1
False
```

Comment: Gustav, thank you so much for replying.  I will try this straight away.  Many thanks - Fingers crossed!!

Comment: Gustav, again many thanks for your reply.  I've just rebuilt the table using the field "currency" and then re-ran the IIF formula and everything has checked back as expected.  Really appreciate your help with this :-)